# SQL Certificate: C# Encrypt and SQL Decrypt

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, certificate, x509certificate

I am creating a certificate in SQL and backing it up to my computer.

I then install the certificate and use it to encrypt some value through a C# program I created (or stole from an article).

If I copy paste the encrypted value and try to decrypt it in SQL then I get `NULL` which means it couldn't decrypt.

I think my issue is that C# is not converting the bytes into recognizable characters for SQL. **Is there a way to output the bytes so that I can copy paste into SQL and decrypt the value correctly?**

SQL - Create Certificate

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE [MyCert]
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd'
    WITH SUBJECT = 'My Sql Certificate'

BACKUP CERTIFICATE [MyCert] TO FILE = 'C:\MyCert.cer'
/* Find certificate and install */
```

C# - Encrypt

```
X509Certificate2 cert = null;
if (this.TryGetCertificate(out cert))
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaEncryptor = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
    byte[] cipherData = rsaEncryptor.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PlainRichTextBox.Text), true);
    CipherRichTextBox.Text = "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(cipherData).Replace("-", "");
}
```

SQL - Decrypt

```
DECLARE @encrypted varbinary(max) = 0xvalueFromEncryptionApp
DECLARE @decrypted varbinary(max) = DECRYPTBYCERT(cert_id('MyCert'), @encrypted, N'P@ssw0rd')
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(max), @decrypted)
```

Result

`NULL`